# Get a dictionary having a specific key value pair from a complex dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I hit a specific scenario where I want to get the dictionary which contains specific value out of a complex dictionary.

For example consider the below dictionary

`a = {"tire1": {"source": "PEP","dest": "host1"},"tire6":{"source": "REP","dest":"host2"}}`

If the value of dest `host1` matches then the function should return `{"tire1": {"source": "PEP","dest": "host1"}` of type dictionary.

**EDIT:** If it matches multiple same values then it should returns multiple matching dictionary in a single dictionary

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: If the value of dest host1 matches means what? are there multiple tire1 in dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You Can do something like this by using dictionary comprehension

```
final_dict = {key: value for key,value in a.items() if value["dest"] == "host1" }
```

Comment: final_dict = {key: value for key,value in a.items() if "host1" in value.values() }

This code will help him to be more generic.

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor What would happen if *"tire6":{"source": "host1","dest":"host2"}* if your suggestion was implemented?

Comment: it will add tire6 in a dictionary too.

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor the op says he wants to keep the dict based on the value associated with `dict`. Your suggestion does not answer the requirement and can lead to unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function with a results list, iterate on the keys and values of dictionary `a`, append to the results list any values (sub-dictionaries) where the `'dest'` key equals `'host1'`, and then return the list of results.

```py
def func(a: dict):
    results = []  # define a list of results to return
    for key, value in a.items():  # iterate on keys values
        if value['dest'] == 'host1': 
            results.append(a[key])  # append that sub-dict to the results

    return results
```

This would return:

```
result = func(a)
print(results)
----
{
    "tire1": 
        {
            "source": "PEP",
            "dest": "host1"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a loop to match the specified value.
In your case, the code is following:

```
dicts = {"tire1": {"source": "PEP","dest": "host1"},"tire6":{"source": "REP","dest":"host2"}}
search_value = 'host1'
for key, values in dicts.items():
  for value in values.values():
    if value == search_value:
      print(f'The Key is {key} and', f'The dictionary are {values}')
```

This will return the matched dictionary with the key. The result will be:

> The Key is tire1 and  The dictionary are {'source': 'PEP', 'dest': 'host1'}

Comment: This is really ineffective. You completely missed the point about how to use a dictionnary.

Comment: I just write the code to match the key and if the key is matched, return the values related to that key. He can do whatever he wants in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust option could be:

```
a = {"tire1": {"source": "PEP", "dest": "host1"},
     "tire6": {"source": "REP", "dest": "host2"}}

result = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if v.get('dest') == 'host1'}

print(result)
```

...in case there are sub-dictionaries where the 'dest' key is absent